# How to convert a ListPlot to a Graph?

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have

```
ListPlot[{{334.`, 460.`}, {339.`, 437.`}, {329.`, 421.`}, {280.`, 
   428.`}, {274.`, 406.`}, {265.`, 419.`}, {255.`, 439.`}, {229.`, 
   436.`}, {205.`, 390.`}, {185.`, 375.`}, {182.`, 417.`}, {189.`, 
   446.`}, {208.`, 472.`}, {222.`, 484.`}, {283.`, 484.`}}]
```

[image]

How to get rid of the `PlotRangePadding` and generate all possible random 
graph from it?

To clarify; the `GraphEmbedding` functionality allowsthe conversion of a graph/associations to a list of coordinates. I guess what I am trying to figure out is the reverse functionality .

Comment: For a start: `img = ListPlot[yourData, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}]; g = MorphologicalGraph@img`. Then you can use `EdgeCount`, `VertexCount` and `RandomGraph`.

Comment: here is "a" random graph. `RandomGraph[{Length@p, 25}, VertexCoordinates -> p]` .  where `p` is your point list.  "All" of them is a really big number you know, like (10^70.)

Comment: @corey979 & @ george2079. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2^105 possible graphs using all the 15 vertices. You can display a very very small fraction of them,e.g.:

The points are given (or extractable from `ListPlot`):

```
pts = {{334.`, 460.`}, {339.`, 437.`}, {329.`, 421.`}, {280.`, 
    428.`}, {274.`, 406.`}, {265.`, 419.`}, {255.`, 439.`}, {229.`, 
    436.`}, {205.`, 390.`}, {185.`, 375.`}, {182.`, 417.`}, {189.`, 
    446.`}, {208.`, 472.`}, {222.`, 484.`}, {283.`, 484.`}};
```

Graph:

```
lg = Length@pts;
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[Range[lg], {2}];
```

Generating random graph:

```
rgf[] := {#, Graph@#} & @@ 
  Module[{el = RandomSample[edges, RandomInteger[{0, 105}]]},
   Graph[Range[lg], el, VertexCoordinates -> pts, 
    VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexStyle -> Red]]
```

Here is a sample of 60:

[image]

Comment: The rgf  snippet code 'rgf[] := {#, Graph@#} & @@ 
  Module[{el = RandomSample[edges, RandomInteger[{0, 105}]]}" did not work.I get the same snippet as an output. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @ElenaD did you run rgf[], after the function definition. You can generate a sample,e.g. Table[rgf[],10]

Comment: @ubpdqn.Yes I did. Sorry for my naive question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ElenaD I just was clarifying. I could have easily made a mistake. Does it work now? If not, perhaps, quit kernel and start fresh.  Hope you achieve your aims:)

Comment: @ubpdqn.It did work. That's exactly what I needed. I also was wondering whether the rgf snippet can accommodate the  RandomGraph functionality instead of RandomSample so I can try  to inject different distributions and see what happen.Any suggestions ?

Comment: @ElenaD this sounds feasible. I suggest that you try with an even smaller toy example and play (I have found this the best way to learn). I you hit an obstacle post another question. Good luck :)